# If $F(U)⊂ U$, then $ϕ : V/U → V/U , v + U → f(v) + U $, but why?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, equivalence-relations

There is given vector space $V$ through a field $K$ and f: $V  → V$ is an Endomorphism. Furthermore, $ U ⊂ V $ is a vector subspace and the following is true : $f(U)⊂ U$

Furthermore there is a mapping $ϕ : V/U → V/U $

In the University our professor sad that if $f(U)⊂ U$ is true, it automatically means $\phi([v]) = f(v) +U$. But I do not see how, I do not undestrand why $\phi([v]) = f(v) +U$ follows $f(U)⊂ U$.

Can somebody please help me out?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have things mixed up.  Here's what I **think** your professor said:

> We're given a vector space $V$ over $K$, an endomorphism $f: V \to V$, and an invariant subspace $U$ (i.e. a subspace $U$ such that $f(U) \subset U$).
>
> Given this information, we can **define** a mapping $\phi:V/U \to V/U$ by
>   $$
> \phi(v + U) = f(v) + U
> $$

Notably, the $\phi$ defined here is often called the map which is *induced* by $\phi$ on $V/U$.  If $f(U) \not\subset U$, then we no longer have the required setup, which is to say that **there is no map $\phi$**.

---

So, assuming the above makes sense to you, you might ask "why was it important to have $f(U) \subset U$?"  Of course, we can always define a map $\psi: V \to V/U$ by 
$$
\psi(v) = f(v) + U
$$
However, in order to make this into a map over the quotient $V/U$, we would need to make sure that the map is well defined.  In particular, it is necessary to have
$$
v + U = w + U \implies f(v) + U = f(w) + U
$$
otherwise, the definition $\phi(v  +  U)  =  f(v) + U$ becomes ambiguous.  By linearity, we can rearrange the above equation:
$$
(v - w) + U = 0 + U \implies f(v - w) + U = U \quad \forall v,w \in V
$$
or in other words,
$$
v-w \in U \implies f(v-w) \in U \quad \forall v,w \in V
$$
but this is equivalent to the statement that $f(U) \subset U$.